# Send pdf on mail using laravel-dompdf without saving on server

Tags: php, laravel, email, pdf

I would like to send pdf on mail using laravel-dompdf without saving on server

I have next code:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.costs.pdf',array('costscategories' => $costscategories,'marketcosts' => $marketcosts,'bonuscosts' => $bonuscosts));
Mail::send('admin.costs.test', $pdf, function($message)
{
    $message->to('test@test.test', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
    $message->attachData($pdf, 'invoice.pdf');
});
}
```

But I get next error:

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/miltonia-update/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 221
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

[Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail) accepts `second argument` as an `array` of data you wish to pass to the `view`. Wrap your `$pdf` as an `array` data.

```
Mail::send('admin.costs.test', ['pdf'=>$pdf], function($message) use ($pdf)
{
   $message->to('test@test.test', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
   $message->attachData($pdf, 'invoice.pdf');
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I get error "base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"  (

Comment: @befreeforlife that's totally irrelevant to this question as there is no specification of base-64_encode(). It would be better if you update your question with new errors or make a new question after solving current problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you need to pass an `array` to `Mail::send` function but you are just passing `$pdf` which is an object and not an array.

**This should work:**

```
$data = [];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.costs.pdf',array('costscategories' => $costscategories,'marketcosts' => $marketcosts,'bonuscosts' => $bonuscosts));

$data['pdf'] = $pdf;

Mail::send('admin.costs.test', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('test@test.test', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
    $message->attachData($data['pdf'], 'invoice.pdf');
});
}
```

Comment: In this case I get error "Undefined variable: data"

Comment: @befreeforlife in that case declare data as a member variable, (`public $data = [ ] ;`) and in mail function, access the data by doing `$this->data['pdf']`

Comment: @befreeforlife aslo remember to assign as `$this->data = $pdf;`

Comment: @SapneshNaik Or may be you could add this line in send() `use ($data)`

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes that would work too. I upvoted your answer as it is more elegant

Comment: So, finaly, I have error "Cannot use object of type Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF as array" (

Comment: @befreeforlife may be you don't need it as you already attached it to the mail. Do you want to show pdf content on email body??

Comment: So, yes, I just would like attach pdf to mail and it done, I don't need show pdf content in body of mail. Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I solve this problem next way, using ideas above:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.costs.pdf',array('costscategories' => $costscategories,'marketcosts' => $marketcosts,'bonuscosts' => $bonuscosts))->stream();

Mail::send('admin.costs.test', ['pdf'=>$pdf], function($message) use ($pdf)
{
   $message->to('test@test.test', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
   $message->attachData($pdf, 'invoice.pdf');
});
```